# Of subtitles & lag times (yet another C overflow doubt)

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the time offset to be added to subtitle files to correct the lag. The part shown below is after tokenizing the `hh:mm:ss,uuu` (uuu stands for microseconds) into the `time[]` array. I'm converting the time into microseconds then adding the actual & lag time to get the final time.

The program computes the actual & lag time properly. However, it gives the wrong final hour time. Have I hit upon some overflow condition that can't be handled by the code below?

**Edit:** I have realized the error. I should be dividing rather than taking remainder for `hour time`.

```
int i;
int time[4];
unsigned long totalTime,totalLagTime;
...
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("time[%d] = %d\n",i,time[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
printf("lag time[%d] = %d\n",i,lagTime[i]);
}

totalTime = 1000*(3600*time[0] + 60*time[1] + time[2]) + time[3];

printf("total time is %u in milliseconds\n",totalTime);

totalLagTime = 1000*(3600*lagTime[0] + 60*lagTime[1] + lagTime[2]) + lagTime[3];

printf("total lag time is %u in milliseconds\n",totalLagTime);

totalTime += totalLagTime;

printf("Now, total time is %u in milliseconds\n",totalTime);

time[0] = totalTime % 3600000;

printf("hour time is %d\n",time[0]);
```

Test case:

```
00:01:24,320

time[0] = 0
time[1] = 1
time[2] = 24
time[3] = 320
lag time[0] = 10
lag time[1] = 10
lag time[2] = 10
lag time[3] = 10
total time is 84320 in milliseconds
total lag time is 36610010 in milliseconds
Now, total time is 36694330 in milliseconds
hour time is 694330
```

Comment: `time[0] = totalTime % 3600000;` What you try to do here ? Are you trying to convert it from millisec to Hour ?

Comment: A lag time of 10 hours, 10 minutes, 10 seconds and 10 milliseconds, for a movie of less than a minute and a half?

Comment: Its a small snippet of a sub file, @Thomas, I wanted to check if if the program worked for extreme cases.

Comment: Now I see the code, I realize it should be `totalTime / 3600000`, thanks Mugen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
time[0] = totalTime / 3600000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error: 36694330 `mod` 3600000 really is 694330.

What are you trying to do, exactly?